# Can't retrieve data from tables in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I can't perform any 'select' query in any tables. `DB::table`, `->where(condition)`, `::find($something)`... nothing works... I can insert data into the tables, but I can't retrieve anything.

I keep getting this error:

> Call to a member function where() on a non-object

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Any suggestion?

Comment: show the actual code, but the error is clear, you're doing `$foo->where`, and `$foo` isn't an object...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't posted any code because I didn't know where the error is coming from.
So I went backwords to the last moment I remembered that the error appeared.
So the problem comes from `DB::table('TableName')->where(...)->get()` 
For my table I use Eloquent and `DB::table`and `where(...)` don't work in this case.. this is what i've found on the internet.
I don't get the error if I use `$results=TableName::find(...)`

Since I'm very new to laravel5 it would be perfect if an experienced member could confirm what I've posted above.